# Find out minimum column values comparing other columns in same row

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I am looking up digital code '0000111100001111' into other lookup table and finding out respective code against each digit.

I am getting 16 column values with respecting to code and i want to find minimum from these

Output I have

```
Channel_code      QA_code1 Priority_1 QA_code2 Priority_2 QA_code3 Priority_3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000111100001111      AB     10         BB      20          CC       30
```

I have such 16 combination in one row

and i have to pick up QA_code who has lowest priority

Answer (score 1):

You could [unpivot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) the data:

```
select *
from your_table
unpivot ((qa_code, priority)
  for n in ((qa_code1, priority_1) as 1,
            (qa_code2, priority_2) as 2,
            (qa_code3, priority_3) as 3))
where channel_code = '0000111100001111';

CHANNEL_CODE              N QA   PRIORITY
---------------- ---------- -- ----------
0000111100001111          1 AB         10
0000111100001111          2 BB         20
0000111100001111          3 CC         30
```

And then [use an aggregate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FIRST.html) to get the value you want:

```
select min(qa_code) keep (dense_rank first order by priority)
from your_table
unpivot ((qa_code, priority)
  for n in ((qa_code1, priority_1) as 1,
            (qa_code2, priority_2) as 2,
            (qa_code3, priority_3) as 3))
where channel_code = '0000111100001111';

MI
--
AB
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e06493e4afede9a897ad5c98cf1168fd)

(The `n` column generated by the unpivot isn't used and the values of that have no significance...)

You might want to move the filter into a subquery, particularly if the data is actually coming form a join rather than a single table.

Comment: Hi Alex.. thanks .. I will check and let you know the same

Comment: Hi @alex Pooie   thanks a lot. It worked perfectly as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for SQL Server, if I am understanding the problem correctly:

```
with cte1(Bitand, QA_code, Priority) as
(
select Channel_code & Priority_1, QA_code1, 1
from t1
union all
select Channel_code & Priority_2, QA_code2, 2
from t1
union all
select Channel_code & Priority_3, QA_code3, 3
from t1
)
select QA_code, Priority
from cte1
where Bitand = (select min(Bitand) from cte1)
```